# ABC Push Value Return

Tags: actionscript-3

I got a question. I have an AS3 code (gotten from AS3 sorcerer)

```
protected function get _-64():String {
    if (_-0Xg < _-1FT.length)
    {
        return (_-1FT[_-0Xg]);
    };

    return ("");
}
```

In ABC code it's (used to decompile + recompile the SWF):

```
  trait getter QName(ProtectedNamespace("_-0t4"), "_-64")
   method
    refid "_-0iF:_-0KH/_-0t4:_-64/getter"
    returns QName(PackageNamespace(""), "String")
    body
     maxstack 2
     localcount 1
     initscopedepth 4
     maxscopedepth 5
     code
      getlocal0
      pushscope

      getlex              QName(PrivateNamespace("", "_-0iF:_-0KH"), "_-0Xg")
      jump                L10

      pushfalse
      pushwith
      subtract
      multiply_i
      coerce_a
      istypelate
    L10:
      getlex              QName(PrivateNamespace("", "_-0iF:_-0KH"), "_-1FT")
      getproperty         QName(PackageNamespace(""), "length")
      ifnlt               L17

      getlex              QName(PrivateNamespace("", "_-0iF:_-0KH"), "_-1FT")
      getlex              QName(PrivateNamespace("", "_-0iF:_-0KH"), "_-0Xg")
      getproperty         MultinameL([PrivateNamespace("", "_-0iF:_-0KH"), PackageNamespace(""), PackageInternalNs("_-0iF"), ProtectedNamespace("_-0t4"), StaticProtectedNs("_-0t4"), StaticProtectedNs("Object"), Namespace("_-tc")])
      returnvalue

    L17:
      pushstring          ""
      returnvalue
     end ; code
    end ; body
    end ; method
    end ; trait
```

However, I want to edit the ABC code so the method (AS3) would look like:

```
protected function get _-64():String {
    return "icon_" + _-0Xg;
}
```

But I have no clue how to push `"icon_" + _-0Xg` in ABC format. Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
getlocal0
pushscope
pushstring "icon_"
getlex QName(PrivateNamespace("", "_-0iF:_-0KH"), "_-0Xg")
add
returnvalue
```